# chromium not opening full URL when started with os.system (py)

Tags: php, python, chromium

I tried to open a url in chromium with os.system, passing GET arguments to the php page. However it seems that chromium doesn't accept or recognize more than one argument.

```
url = "chromium-browser localhost/index.php?temp=" + str(int(math.floor(get_temperature()))) + "&id=" + get_id()
print(url)
os.system(url)
```

String being printed:
chromium-browser localhost/index.php?temp=15&id=10

URL being opened:
http://localhost/index.php?temp=15

---

#### Solved

Wrapping the URL in quotes solved the issue.

Comment: If you type `chromium-browser localhost/index.php?temp=15&id=10` on the command-line of your operating system, what happens? (Hint: you may want to try wrapping the parameter with the ampersand in it in quotes)

Comment: thank you, wrapping it fixed the issue

Comment: Instead of using `+` to concatenate, I recommend using the `{}`.format style: `url = "chromium-browser localhost/index.php?temp={}&id={}".format(math.floor(get_temperature()), get_id())` -- it will coerce all types to string so you don't have to wrap your arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a command to a subshell. The ampersand has a special meaning to a Unix shell; it [puts the preceding command in the background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line).

Ignoring Python completely, if you were to run this from the command line:

```
chromium-browser localhost/index.php?temp=15&id=10
```

...you'd find that it would execute the command:

```
chromium-browser localhost/index.php?temp=15
```

...in the background, and then attempt to execute the command:

```
id=10
```

in the foreground. That last bit would likely fail, as it's not a valid command, but the first command would succeed.

To solve the problem, you need to escape the ampersand; the best way to do this is probably just to wrap the whole URL you're passing in quotes:

```
chromium-browser "localhost/index.php?temp=15&id=10"
```

So perhaps something like this would be appropriate:

```
command_line='chromium-browser "http://localhost/index.php?temp={0}&id={1}"'
os.system(command_line.format(math.floor(get_temperature()), get_id()))
```