# open specific link in chrome browser using PHP or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am using **PHP codeigniter** on **ubuntu** where I want to **open specific link in chrome browser**. like on button click "https://stackoverflow.com/" will open in chrome browser. I can open it from terminal using below command

```
chromium-browser https://stackoverflow.com
```

but it do not run from PHP

```
exec("chromium-browser https://stackoverflow.com");
```

I can use file_get_contents but I can not restrict chrome browser only.

Comment: There is [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923331/solved-chromium-not-opening-full-url-when-started-with-os-system-py) linking **[this github library](https://github.com/gsouf/headless-chromium-php)**, have u tried?

Comment: I will check that. Thank you.

Comment: You have 374 reputation, a 'top %56 this quarter badge', not typed on google "how to open a url on chromium browser with php" and still don't know how to thank you. You should visit **[Tour page on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Comment: @Erhan Yaşar : I searched using chrome instead of chromium and found nothing useful

Comment: @Renati : My question is for specific browser even PHP script is running on firefox I want to open chrome using script.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this is impossible. Tou try execute command from server (PHP) for open a program to the client (browser). You must try it in javascript.